# Check table for relations before deleting

Tags: c#

I'm trynig to check if a Parameter has some values before deleting it. If the Parameter has values than it should return true. I am using this code:

```
private bool HasValue()
{
    return Factory.Definitions.CalculationParametersValues
        .List().Any(a => Factory.Definitions.CalculationParameters
            .List().Any(b => a.CalculationParameterId == b.Id)).Any();
}

//Factory.Definitions.CalculationParametersValues.List() lists the data from database table
//Factory.Definitions.CalculationParameters.List() lists the data from database table
```

Values contain the Parameter's `Id` as `CalculationParameterId`.

It always returns true. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Someone correct me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private bool HasValue(int idparameter)
{
    return Factory.Definitions.CalculationParametersValues.Any(a=>a.Id== idparameter);
}
```